# InputSimulator Keyboard.TextEntry is not working

Tags: c#, asynchronous, input, process, notepad

I'm trying to open a notepad instance and write a virtual text entry to it. The notepad opens securely but nothing is written on it. What would be the problem and why?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WindowsInput;
using WindowsInput.Native;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Process notepadProcess = new Process();

            notepadProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";

            notepadProcess.Start();

            InputSimulator simulator = new InputSimulator();

            simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry("This is a message that will be written to Notepad");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error opening Notepad: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to pause the execution thread to allow time for the notepad to start, but I only managed to get it typed if I moved the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot tell InputSimulator which process the text should be sent to, the focus must be set to the recipient *notepadProcess* (before sending).
It should be noted that Notepad consists of a control for the menu and a control for the edit area. The focus of your text must be on the latter.
You set this with your mouse click.